plot a distribution over time
Very new to R.
I've been struggling with a very simple question, but I can't find a way around it
I need to be able to see the distribution of assets across time.
Here's the code. What I have in mind is a 3D plot, with the axes being: time, density and assets. For some reason, that plot doesn't work.
library(fdicdata)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


data <- getInstitutionsAll()
#data_history <- getHistory()
bank_data <- data[,c('CERT', 'ASSET', 'DATEUPDT', 'DEP', 'EQ', 'ESTYMD', 'INSDATE', 'NEWCERT', 'REPDTE', 'RISDATE',
                     'ROA', 'ROAPTX', 'ROE', 'DEPDOM', 'NETINC')]


bank_data <- bank_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(REPDTE, RISDATE,DATEUPDT, INSDATE), mdy)%>%
  mutate_at(vars(ASSET, DEP, EQ, ROA, ROAPTX, ROE, DEPDOM ,NETINC), as.numeric)

fails <- getFailures(c("CERT", "NAME", "FAILDATE", "CITY", "STATE", 'SAVR', 'COST', 'QBFDEP', 'QBFASSET', 'PSTALP'), range = c(1992, 2023))


densities <- bank_data %>%
  group_by(REPDTE) %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(ASSET)) >= 2) %>%
  do({
    d <- density(.$ASSET, na.rm = TRUE)
    data.frame(REPDTE = unique(.$REPDTE), 
               density_x = d$x, 
               density_y = d$y)
  }) %>%
  ungroup()

# Prepare data for 3D plotting
# Convert the data frame into matrices for plotly's surface plot
time_unique <- unique(densities$REPDTE)
x_values <- sort(unique(densities$density_x))

# Create a matrix of density values for each time point
density_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(x_values), ncol = length(time_unique))

for (i in 1:length(time_unique)) {
  subset_data <- densities %>% filter(REPDTE == time_unique[i])
  density_matrix[, i] <- approx(subset_data$density_x, subset_data$density_y, xout = x_values, rule = 2)$y
}

# Plot 3D surface
p1 <- plot_ly(x = x_values, 
        y = time_unique, 
        z = t(density_matrix), # Transpose to align with time and asset values
        type = "surface") %>%
  layout(title = "3D Plot of Asset Densities Over Time",
         scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Asset Values"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "Time"),
                      zaxis = list(title = "Density")))


I get a grey box.

You can try a library like Threejs for easy 3D plotting https://bwlewis.github.io/rthreejs/

Are you able to sample from the full data set for this visualization? The code is fine, but is trying to create an interactive plot from a matrix with >13 million elements. As a test you can pull a few quarters or years from densities and check that the resulting plot is what you are aiming for. e.g. densities <- densities |> filter(between(year(REPDTE),1984,1988))

You might also look at the ggdist package for some world-tested non-3D approaches to showing distributions.

As @Seth points out, plotting 13 million density values may be computationally challenging. Subsampling
Trying the rgl package in hopes that it will be a little more performant (although maybe harder to prettify):
rgl::persp3d(x_values, time_unique, density_matrix, col = "gray")

(This takes about 15 seconds to render on a mid-range modern laptop.)

This might be a little easier to see, although still kind of ugly:
d3d <- log10(density_matrix+1e-10)  ## 
rgl::persp3d(x_values, time_unique, d3d, col = "gray")


You could subsample with something like this:
keeprows <- which(seq(nrow(density_matrix)) %% 10 == 0)
keepcols <- which(seq(ncol(density_matrix)) %% 10 == 0)
rgl::persp3d(x_values[keeprows], time_unique[keepcols], density_matrix[keeprows, keepcols], col = "gray")

